# Variable scope for titanium alloy

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I would like to know how the variable scope works when Ti.include.

I made application on titanium 2.*

```
var x = '12'

Ti.include('lib.js');
```

in lib.js

```
Ti.API.info(x) //it shows 12
```

However, now I am transferring this code into alloy

in app/controllers/index.js

```
var x = '12'

Ti.include('/mylib/lib.js');
```

in app/ssets/mylib/lib.js

```
app/ssets/mylib/lib.js // it says can't find variable x.
```

How can I make the global variable which is available in both file??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to assign global variable you can use `Alloy.Globals` object:

```
Alloy.Globals.myVar = 12;
```

Also instead of using Ti.include, it's much better to use `require();` and convert your code to *CommonJS* module, so you will be able set which variable and functions you want to export:

**/app/lib/util.js**:

```
var privateValue = 'foo';

var publicValue = 'bar';

function getValues() {
    return [privateValue, publicValue];
}

module.exports = {
    publicValue: publicValue,
    getValues: getValues,
};
```

**/app/controllers/index.js**:

```
var util = require('/util');

Ti.App.info(util.privateValue); // undefined
Ti.App.info(util.publicValue); // 'bar'

util.publicValue = 'foobar';

Ti.App.info(util.getValues()); // [ 'foo', 'foobar' ];
```

Comment: Thanks daniula I will use Alloy.Globals. for now. Then keep learning about 'lib'

Comment: One caveat about global vars: Use them sparingly. Being global also means no garbage collection. EVERYTHING declared in `alloy.js` stays in memory for the duration of the app's lifecycle. Remember, just because you can doesn't mean you should.